# phpunit halts to then restart and terminate the remaining tests

Tags: php, phpunit

My phpunit has started behaving in a strange way after upgrading my ubuntu to 12.04. I don't know if it can be related or not but I thought it was worth mentioning. Anyhow the problem is the following:

during the execution of the tests phpunit stops at some point (I would say around the 50th test) for about 10 seconds to then restart and complete all the testing. It works fine otherwise, only I am wasting a lot of time when running the tests. As u can immagine I don't really like that as tests are supposed to run uber fast, are't they?

Any idea what it could cause this?

Comment: Does the problem happen on the same unit test every time?  Have you made any change to that unit test?

Comment: nope! basically each unit test runs fine when executed independently. When I run them all in one go though, the weird behaviour appears. It's strange cuz in ubuntu < 12.04 it all works fine (all tests executed in no time). before updating the computer that now has the 12.04 installed everything was fine too.